# Detecting images saturation level with command line ImageMagick and outputting to JSON

Tags: json, command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to get the saturation level of an image, to calculate if it is closer to being greyscale or colour. This needs to work on any image file format. I also need to be able to get the other information, including file type, mime type, width, height, and possibly the perceptual hash moments. It also needs to remain the JSON output.

Currently I am using `convert image.png json:-` which outputs almost all of the data I need, with the exception of the image saturation. I tried `convert image.png -colorspace HSL json:-`, under the assumption that it would change the channels from red, green and blue (and gray) to hue, saturation and lightness, but it remained the former.

When using the RGB colorspace, a greyscale image returns just two channelStatistics, alpha and gray, while a colour image returns alpha, red, green and blue. When using HSL, it returns alpha, red, green and blue for greyscale and colour, in the following format (this is a greyscale example):

```
[channelStatistics] -> Object
(
    [alpha] => stdClass Object
        (
            [min] => 255
            [max] => 255
            [mean] => 255
            [standardDeviation] => 0
            [kurtosis] => 0
            [skewness] => 0
        )

    [red] => stdClass Object
        (
            [min] => 0
            [max] => 0
            [mean] => 0
            [standardDeviation] => 0
            [kurtosis] => 0
            [skewness] => 0
        )

    [green] => stdClass Object
        (
            [min] => 0
            [max] => 0
            [mean] => 0
            [standardDeviation] => 0
            [kurtosis] => 0
            [skewness] => 0
        )

    [blue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [min] => 20
            [max] => 255
            [mean] => 230.007
            [standardDeviation] => 44.1297
            [kurtosis] => 2.21673
            [skewness] => -1.80749
        )

)
```

What command would return the information I need? I do not want to alter the original image; it needs to remain untouched. I just need to get these certain details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
convert input.png -colorspace hsl json:
```

the output is actually in HSL, except it is, somehwat misleadingly, labelled as Red, Green and Blue.

You can test this by creating an image that is pretty much red but with a little variation in it so that IM can't encode it as a palettised image like this:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 gradient:"rgb(255,0,0)-rgb(230,10,0)" input.png
```

Now if you look at the JSON it looks like this - largely fully saturated bright Red

```
"channelStatistics": {
  "red": {
    "min": "59110",
    "max": "65535",
    "mean": "62322.5",
    "standardDeviation": "1856.6",
    "kurtosis": "-1.19999",
    "skewness": "1.52719e-06"
  },
  "green": {
    "min": "0",
    "max": "2570",
    "mean": "1285",
    "standardDeviation": "742.641",
    "kurtosis": "-1.19999",
    "skewness": "0"
  },
  "blue": {
    "min": "0",
    "max": "0",
    "mean": "0",
    "standardDeviation": "0",
    "kurtosis": "0",
    "skewness": "0"
  }
},
```

and if you convert to HSL

```
convert input.png -colorspace hsl json:
```

it now looks like this:

```
"channelStatistics": {
  "red": {
    "min": "0",
    "max": "475",
    "mean": "229.308",
    "standardDeviation": "137.131",
    "kurtosis": "-1.19385",
    "skewness": "0.071888"
  },
  "green": {
    "min": "65535",
    "max": "65535",
    "mean": "65535",
    "standardDeviation": "0",
    "kurtosis": "0",
    "skewness": "0"
  },
  "blue": {
    "min": "29555",
    "max": "32768",
    "mean": "31161.5",
    "standardDeviation": "928.298",
    "kurtosis": "-1.20001",
    "skewness": "1.58408e-08"
  }
},
```

It may be *sold* as Red, Green and Blue, but actually the "Red" is the **Hue** which is close to zero, i.e. red, and the "Green" is actually the **Saturation** and you can see it is fully saturated, and the "Blue" is the **Lightness** which is mid grey.

Comment: Thank you. And in case any future readers (and there will be some, I'm sure!) see this, I then calculated it by getting the `mean` value of `green`, and then checking if it is `> 0.1`. If it is, it's colour, most likely, and if it isn't, it's greyscale. I _might_ have to tweak the value, but it looks pretty solid in tests so far.